# Magento html-head dropdown missing

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I wanted to modify my title prefix and suffix but this option seems to have gone missing.
I searched for Configuration => Design => HTML Head
the HTML Head dropdown however seems to be missing.

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

if you use a local code folder - simply copy

*app/code/core/Mage/Page/etc/system.xml*

to

*app/code/local/Mage/Page/etc/system.xml*

afterwards the HTML Head Section should re-appear.

Comment: It helped me a lot. Thanks