# Unable to find header tab under system->configuration->design in magento 1.9.1

Tags: magento, header

I have try to change default welcome message in magento 1.9.1.after some analysis i found that i need to change it in header in system->configuration->design tab.But am unable to find the header tab in magento 1.9.1

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a step..

```
 System > Configuration > GENERAL > Design
```

Comment: yes in system > configuration >general >design tab there is no header option to change the default welcome message.how can i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve this issue.

> First is to install new fresh magento which takes long process.

**OR**

> 1. Copy the core file system.xml in app/code/core/Mage/Page/etc
> 2. Create a similar directory folder in local folder (app/code/local/Mage/Page/etc)
> 3. Paste the system.xml on that directory
> 4. Clear your cache and refresh your page.

If the tab is still missing check your local folder and its file names. If there are no discrepancy, proceed to the first option.

I'm not sure if this is a bug of magento. It usually occurs during installation of magento upgrade.

You can refer to this links.

[Missing HTML Head section from admin system->configuration->Design in magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16897404/missing-html-head-section-from-admin-system-configuration-design-in-magento)

[Magento html-head dropdown missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909156/magento-html-head-dropdown-missing)